# R: Aligning data frame columns with actual columns

Tags: r

I have the following data frame

```
Loci      p-value             chromosome    start     end        geneDescription
A         2.046584849E-2      1             98542     98699      tyrosine kinase
B         5.67849483E-20      2             8958437   8958437    endocytosis
...
```

However, when I want to print the data frame with the following code:

```
write.table(table,"~/Desktop/genes.txt", sep = "\t", row.names = FALSE, col.names = TRUE, quote = FALSE, append = FALSE)
```

I get the following:

```
 Loci      p-value chromosome    start     end   geneDescription
 A         2.046584849E-20       1         98542    98699          tyrosine kinase
 B         5.67849483E-20        2         8958437  8958437        endocytosis
```

I know that it has to do with the "\t", but can R adjust automatically the width of the columns when printing to get the original data frame above?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "print the data frame"?

Comment: Well, the data frame is stored in the variable table. When I want to write the data frame (column names and values), I would like to write it in a file called "genes.txt" exactly the same way as shown in View(table)

Answer (score 0):

No, since this is a tab formatting issue and can be partially solved by increasing the tabwidth on you editor. Try normalizing the length of the column names.

```
max.name <- max(sapply(colnames(table), nchar))
colnames(table) <- sapply(colnames(table), function(name) paste0(c(name, rep(" ", max.name - nchar(name))), collapse = ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're just looking for `capture.output` or `sink`.

In the following examples, replace `x` with an actual file name. This is just done for illustrative purposes.

```
x <- tempfile()
capture.output(mydf, file=x)
readLines(x)
# [1] "  Loci      p.value chromosome   start     end geneDescription"
# [2] "1    A 2.046585e-02          1   98542   98699  tyrosinekinase"
# [3] "2    B 5.678495e-20          2 8958437 8958437     endocytosis"

x <- tempfile()
sink(file = x)
mydf
sink()
readLines(x)
# [1] "  Loci      p.value chromosome   start     end geneDescription"
# [2] "1    A 2.046585e-02          1   98542   98699  tyrosinekinase"
# [3] "2    B 5.678495e-20          2 8958437 8958437     endocytosis"
```

The `readLines` step is just to show you what was written to your "file".